# Basic WebRTC DataChannel MCVE not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I'm working on a web app that uses WebRTC DataChannel, and I can't get the channel open in Chrome. I've reduced it to a simple test that opens two `RTCPeerConnection` instances on the same page with signaling directly in the code ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0bze2La/1/)):

```
'use strict';

var RTCPC_CONFIG = {
  'iceServers': [
    { 'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
  ]
};

var RTCPC_OPTIONAL = { optional: [{ RtpDataChannels: true }] };

var DATACHANNEL_OPTIONS = {
};

// Create offering peer and data channel.
var offPeer = new RTCPeerConnection(RTCPC_CONFIG, RTCPC_OPTIONAL);
var offChan = offPeer.createDataChannel('off', DATACHANNEL_OPTIONS);

offChan.onopen = function() {
  console.log('***** offering channel open *****');
};

// Create answering peer and data channel.
var ansPeer = new RTCPeerConnection(RTCPC_CONFIG, RTCPC_OPTIONAL);
var ansChan = ansPeer.createDataChannel('ans', DATACHANNEL_OPTIONS);

ansChan.onopen = function() {
  console.log('***** answering channel open *****');
};

// Create the WebRTC offer.
var exchangeDescriptions = offPeer.createOffer().then(function(offer) {
  offPeer.setLocalDescription(offer);
  console.log('offer\n' + JSON.stringify(offer, null, 2));

  // Set the offer on the other peer.
  return ansPeer.setRemoteDescription(offer);
}).then(function() {
  // Create the WebRTC answer.
  return ansPeer.createAnswer();
}).then(function(answer) {
  ansPeer.setLocalDescription(answer);
  console.log('answer\n' + JSON.stringify(answer, null, 2));

  // Set the answer on the other peer.
  return offPeer.setRemoteDescription(answer);
});

// Collect and exchange ICE candidates.
offPeer.onicecandidate = function(e) {
  if (e.candidate) {
    var ice = e.candidate;
    exchangeDescriptions.then(function() {
      // Add ICE candidate to other peer.
      console.log('offer ICE\n' + JSON.stringify(e.candidate, null, 2));
      ansPeer.addIceCandidate(ice);
    });
  }
  else
    console.log('offer ICE done');
};

ansPeer.onicecandidate = function(e) {
  if (e.candidate) {
    var ice = e.candidate;
    exchangeDescriptions.then(function() {
      // Add ICE candidate to other peer.
      console.log('answer ICE\n' + JSON.stringify(e.candidate, null, 2));
      offPeer.addIceCandidate(ice);
    });
  }
  else
    console.log('answer ICE done');
};
```

Please note that on the [jsfiddle page](https://jsfiddle.net/L0bze2La/1/) I am using the [WebRTC adapter](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) to shim the browser API to the spec.

When you run this script with the Javascript console open, I expect to see the DataChannel reported open amidst all the logging:

```
***** offering channel open *****
***** answering channel open *****
```

I do see this on Firefox 43, but not on Chrome 48 (stable) or 50 (canary).

Where am I going wrong with Chrome? I have tried other samples that use DataChannel and some work, so I know Chrome supports it. Sample code often uses older or browser-specific APIs which I would rather not simply copy. As far as I can tell I am doing the same things, but that is obviously not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, the problem seems to be this setting which I picked up from sample code on several sites:

```
var RTCPC_OPTIONAL = { optional: [{ RtpDataChannels: true }] };
```

Apparently the `RtpDataChannels` is a legacy Chrome thing which is [no longer supported](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/VBuCK-37BCo). If I remove that extra argument from the `RTCPeerConnection` constructors then [things work on Chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/L0bze2La/2/).

I [filed an issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587563) on Chrome.